# Oracle SQL Join Data Sequentially

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to track the usage of material with my SQL. There is no way in our database to link when a part is used to the order it originally came from. A part simply ends up in a bin after an order arrives, and then usage of parts basically just creates a record for the number of parts used at a time of transaction. I am attempting to, as best I can, link usage to an order number by summing over the data and sequentially assigning it to order numbers.
My sub queries have gotten me this far. Each order number is received on a date. I then join the usage table records based on the USEDATE needing to be equal to or greater than the RECEIVEDATE of the order. The data produced by this is as such:

```
| ORDERNUM |  PARTNUM |       RECEIVEDATE       |  ORDERQTY |  USEQTY |        USEDATE         |
|----------|----------|-------------------------|-----------|---------|------------------------|
|     4412 |  E1125   |  10/26/2016 1:32:25 PM  |         1 |       1 |  11/18/2016 1:40:55 PM |
|     4412 |  E1125   |  10/26/2016 1:32:25 PM  |         1 |       3 |  12/26/2016 2:19:32 PM |
|     4412 |  E1125   |  10/26/2016 1:32:25 PM  |         1 |       1 |  1/3/2017 8:31:21 AM   |
|     4111 |  E1125   |  10/28/2016 2:54:13 PM  |         1 |       1 |  11/18/2016 1:40:55 PM |
|     4111 |  E1125   |  10/28/2016 2:54:13 PM  |         1 |       3 |  12/26/2016 2:19:32 PM |
|     4111 |  E1125   |  10/28/2016 2:54:13 PM  |         1 |       1 |  1/3/2017 8:31:21 AM   |
|     0393 |  E1125   |  12/22/2016 11:52:04 AM |         3 |       3 |  12/26/2016 2:19:32 PM |
|     0393 |  E1125   |  12/22/2016 11:52:04 AM |         3 |       1 |  1/3/2017 8:31:21 AM   |
|     7812 |  E1125   |  12/27/2016 10:56:01 AM |         1 |       1 |  1/3/2017 8:31:21 AM   |
|     1191 |  E1125   |  1/5/2017 1:12:01 PM    |         2 |       0 |  null                  |
```

The query for the above section looks as such:

```
SELECT 
B.*, 
NVL(B2.QTY, ‘0’) USEQTY
B2.USEDATE USEDATE
FROM <<Sub Query B>>
LEFT JOIN USETABLE B2 ON B.PARTNUM = B2.PARTNUM AND B2.USEDATE >= B.RECEIVEDATE
```

My ultimate goal here is to join USEQTY records sequentially until they have filled enough ORDERQTY’s. I also need to add an ORDERUSE column that represents what QTY from the USEQTY column was actually applied to that record. Not really sure how to word this any better so here is example of what I need to happen based on the table above:

```
| ORDERNUM |  PARTNUM |       RECEIVEDATE       |  ORDERQTY |  USEQTY |         USEDATE        |  ORDERUSE |
|----------|----------|-------------------------|-----------|---------|------------------------|-----------|
|     4412 |  E1125   |  10/26/2016 1:32:25 PM  |         1 |       1 |  11/18/2016 1:40:55 PM |         1 |
|     4111 |  E1125   |  10/28/2016 2:54:13 PM  |         1 |       3 |  12/26/2016 2:19:32 PM |         1 |
|     0393 |  E1125   |  12/22/2016 11:52:04 AM |         3 |       2 |  12/26/2016 2:19:32 PM |         2 |
|     0393 |  E1125   |  12/22/2016 11:52:04 AM |         3 |       1 |  1/3/2017 8:31:21 AM   |         1 |
|     7812 |  E1125   |  12/27/2016 10:56:01 AM |         1 |       0 |  null                  |         0 |
|     1191 |  E1125   |  1/5/2017 1:12:01 PM    |         2 |       0 |  null                  |         0 |
```

If I can get the query to pull the information like above, I will then be able to group the records together and sum the ORDERUSE column which would get me the information I need to know what orders have been used and which have not been fully used. So in the example above, if I were to sum the ORDERUSE column for each of the ORDERNUMs, orders 4412, 4111, 0393 would all show full usage. Orders 7812, 1191 would show not being fully used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am reading this correctly you want to determine how many parts have been used. In your example it looks like you have 5 usages and with 5 orders coming to a total of 8 parts with the following orders having been used.

- 4412 - one part - one used
- 4111 - one part - one used
- 7812 - one part - one used
- 0393 - three
  parts - two used

After a bit of hacking away I came up with the following SQL. Not sure if this works outside of your sample data since thats the only thing I used to test and I am no expert.

```
WITH data 
 AS (SELECT * 
     FROM   (SELECT * 
             FROM   sub_b1 
                    join (SELECT ROWNUM rn 
                          FROM   dual 
                          CONNECT BY LEVEL < 15) a 
                      ON a.rn <= sub_b1.orderqty 
             ORDER  BY receivedate) 
     WHERE  ROWNUM <= (SELECT SUM(useqty) 
                       FROM   sub_b2)) 
SELECT sub_b1.ordernum, 
   partnum, 
   receivedate, 
   orderqty, 
   usage 
FROM   sub_b1 
   join (SELECT ordernum, 
                Max(rn) AS usage 
         FROM   data 
         GROUP  BY ordernum) b 
     ON sub_b1.ordernum = b.ordernum
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "FIFO" inventory accounting.

The proper data model should have two tables, one for "received" parts and the other for "delivered" or "used". Each table should show an order number, a part number and quantity (received or used) for that order, and a timestamp or date-time. I model both in CTE's in my query below, but in your business they should be two separate table. Also, a trigger or similar should enforce the constraint that a part cannot be used until it is available in stock (that is: for each part id, the total quantity used since inception, at any point in time, should not exceed the total quantity received since inception, also at the same point in time). I assume that the two input tables do, in fact, satisfy this condition, and I don't check it in the solution.

The output shows a timeline of quantity used, by timestamp, matching "received" and "delivered" (used) quantities for each part_id. In the sample data I illustrate a single part_id, but the query will work with multiple part_id's, and orders (both for received and for delivered or used) that include multiple parts (part id's) with different quantities.

```
with
     received  ( order_id, part_id, ts, qty ) as (
       select '0030', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-18 15:00:33', 20 from dual union all
       select '0032', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-22 15:00:33', 13 from dual union all
       select '0034', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-24 10:00:33', 18 from dual union all
       select '0036', '11A4', timestamp '2015-04-01 15:00:33', 25 from dual
     ),
     delivered ( order_id, part_id, ts, qty ) as (
       select '1200', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-18 16:30:00', 14 from dual union all
       select '1210', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-23 10:30:00',  8 from dual union all
       select '1220', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-23 11:30:00',  7 from dual union all
       select '1230', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-23 11:30:00',  4 from dual union all
       select '1240', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-26 15:00:33',  1 from dual union all
       select '1250', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-26 16:45:11',  3 from dual union all
       select '1260', '11A4', timestamp '2015-03-27 10:00:33',  2 from dual union all
       select '1270', '11A4', timestamp '2015-04-03 15:00:33', 16 from dual
     ),
```

(end of test data; the SQL query begins below - just add the word `WITH` at the top)

```
-- with
     combined ( part_id, rec_ord, rec_ts, rec_sum, del_ord, del_ts, del_sum) as (
       select part_id, order_id, ts,
              sum(qty) over (partition by part_id order by ts, order_id), 
              null, cast(null as date), cast(null as number)
         from received
       union all
       select part_id, null, cast(null as date), cast(null as number),
              order_id, ts,
              sum(qty) over (partition by part_id order by ts, order_id)
         from delivered
     ),
     prep ( part_id, rec_ord, del_ord, del_ts, qty_sum ) as (
       select part_id, rec_ord, del_ord, del_ts, coalesce(rec_sum, del_sum)
       from   combined 
     ) 
select   part_id,
         last_value(rec_ord ignore nulls) over (partition by part_id
                                                order by qty_sum desc) as rec_ord,
         last_value(del_ord ignore nulls) over (partition by part_id
                                                order by qty_sum desc) as del_ord,
         last_value(del_ts  ignore nulls) over (partition by part_id
                                                order by qty_sum desc) as used_date,
         qty_sum - lag(qty_sum, 1, 0) over (partition by part_id
                                            order by qty_sum, del_ts)  as used_qty
from     prep
order by qty_sum
;
```

**Output**:

```
PART_ID REC_ORD DEL_ORD USED_DATE                             USED_QTY
------- ------- ------- ----------------------------------- ----------
11A4    0030    1200    18-MAR-15 04.30.00.000000000 PM             14
11A4    0030    1210    23-MAR-15 10.30.00.000000000 AM              6
11A4    0032    1210    23-MAR-15 10.30.00.000000000 AM              2
11A4    0032    1220    23-MAR-15 11.30.00.000000000 AM              7
11A4    0032    1230    23-MAR-15 11.30.00.000000000 AM              4
11A4    0032    1230    23-MAR-15 11.30.00.000000000 AM              0
11A4    0034    1240    26-MAR-15 03.00.33.000000000 PM              1
11A4    0034    1250    26-MAR-15 04.45.11.000000000 PM              3
11A4    0034    1260    27-MAR-15 10.00.33.000000000 AM              2
11A4    0034    1270    03-APR-15 03.00.33.000000000 PM             12
11A4    0036    1270    03-APR-15 03.00.33.000000000 PM              4
11A4    0036                                                        21

12 rows selected.
```

**Notes**: (1) One needs to be careful if at one moment the cumulative used quantity exactly matches cumulative received quantity. All rows must be include in all the intermediate results, otherwise there will be bad data in the output; but this may result (as you can see in the output above) in a few rows with a "used quantity" of 0. Depending on how this output is consumed (for further processing, for reporting, etc.) these rows may be left as they are, or they may be discarded in a further outer-query with the condition `where used_qty > 0`.

(2) The last row shows a quantity of 21 with no `used_date` and no `del_ord`. This is, in fact, the "current" quantity in stock for that part_id as of the last date in both tables - available for future use. Again, if this is not needed, it can be removed in an outer query. There may be one or more rows like this at the end of the table.

Comment: The problem I have is that our usage table does not have an order number, because there is no way to add one. I believe its simply poor design on our part, When parts arrive, they simply get tossed into a bin. At that point, there is no serial number or any other kind of tracking done on the part. So when one is ordered out, its just pulled from a bin and sent up, and the usage record simply records the parts number, the quantity and the timestamp.